# How do I add HtmlAttributes in mvc using ViewBag or Model values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

I have a textarea that I might want to disable in certain conditions. I want to send this information as a ViewBag parameter, but I can't figure out how to do it.

The textarea in my view looks like this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(f => f.ProgressDetail, new { @class = "followUpProgress", ViewBag.DisableProgressDetail })
```

And in the controller I have something like this:

```
if(conditions)
    ViewBag.DisableProgressDetail = "disabled=\"disabled\"";
```

The html output, however, is this:

```
<textarea DisableProgressDetail="disabled=&quot;disabled&quot;" class="followUpProgress" cols="20" id="ProgressDetail" name="ProgressDetail" rows="2">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(f => f.ProgressDetail, new { @class = "followUpProgress", disabled = ViewBag.DisableProgressDetail })
```

Then in your controller, just make it:

```
ViewBage.DisableProgressDetail = "disabled";
```

Comment: I was actually just about to post that as my own answer when I saw that a new answer had arrived. :)

Answer (score 1):

The attribute if not specified comes from the name of the property, that is why you are getting an html attribute named for the ViewBag property. One way to get it working would be:

```
// in the view:
@Html.TextAreaFor(f => f.ProgressDetail, new { @class = "followUpProgress", ViewBag.disabled })
-------------------------------------------------------------
// in the controller
ViewBag.disabled = "disabled";
```

If you don't like that approach you might just set the disabled bit like this:

```
// in the view:
@Html.TextAreaFor(f => f.ProgressDetail, new { @class = "followUpProgress", disabled=ViewBag.DisableProgressDetail })
-------------------------------------------------------------
// in the controller:
if(conditions)
    ViewBag.DisableProgressDetail = "disabled";
else
    ViewBag.DisableProgressDetail = "false";

// or more simply
ViewBag.DisableProgressDetail = (conditions) ? "disabled" : "false";
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn´t work. You can try this:

```
//In the controller

if(Mycondition){ ViewBag.disabled = true;}
else { ViewBag.disabled = false;}

//In the view

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyProperty, ViewBag.disabled ? (object)new { @class = "MyClass", size = "20", maxlength = "20", disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { @class = "MyClass", size = "20", maxlength = "20" })
```